# SQLAlchemy with multiple databases and error due to duplicate index creation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

We have a postgres database with two tables `Models` and `Drives` and we create queries using sqlalchemy to analyze the data in these tables.

`Models` table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE models (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    vendor_name character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    model character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    drive_capacity bigint NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX models_pkey ON models(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_models_vendor_name ON models(vendor_name text_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_models_model ON models(model text_ops);
```

and represented by a `Models` class in `tables.py`:

```
class Models(Base, DeferredReflection):
    __tablename__ = "models"
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
```

`Drives` tables has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE drives (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    serial_number character varying(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    model integer NOT NULL REFERENCES models(id),
    role character varying(16) NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX drives_pkey ON drives(id int4_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX drives_serial_number_key ON drives(serial_number text_ops);
CREATE INDEX drives_role_idx ON drives(role text_ops);
CREATE INDEX index_drives_model_fk ON drives(model int4_ops);
```

and is represented with a `Drives` class in `tables.py`:

```
class Drives(Base, DeferredReflection):
    __tablename__ = "drives"
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    model = Column("model", Integer, ForeignKey(Models.id), nullable=False)
```

As you can notice, both the tables have additional indices created on specific columns. In our unit test infrastructure, we create a in-memory sqlite database and create tables and indices with same schema as the postgresql database. We then insert fake rows to the sqlite instance, run our real queries on top of the sqlite database and check the correctness of the real queries. The code looks like this:

```
sqlite_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
from tables import Base
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=sqlite_engine)
# add fake rows to sqlite
# run real query on sqlite engine
# compare against expected output to confirm correctness of real queries.
```

However, I get an error in the `create_all` step above. While I'm able to create the models table and its indices, I get an index already exists error for the `drives` table:

```
cursor = <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f466b877570>
statement = 'CREATE INDEX index_drives_model_fk ON drives (model)'
parameters = ()
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteExecutionContext object at 0x7f466b2f4160>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) index index_drives_model_fk already exists [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX index_drives_model_fk ON drives (model)'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

With `echo=True`, I notice that SQLAlchemy emits the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE models (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    vendor_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    drive_capacity BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT models_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
log.py                     110 INFO     COMMIT
log.py                     110 INFO     CREATE INDEX idx_models_model ON models (model)
log.py                     110 INFO     COMMIT
log.py                     110 INFO     CREATE INDEX idx_models_vendor_name ON models (vendor_name)
log.py                     110 INFO     COMMIT
log.py                     110 INFO
CREATE TABLE drives (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    model INTEGER NOT NULL,
    serial_number VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    role VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT drives_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY(model) REFERENCES models (id),
    CONSTRAINT drives_serial_number_key UNIQUE (serial_number),
    CONSTRAINT drives_serial_number_key UNIQUE (serial_number)
)
log.py                     110 INFO     COMMIT
log.py                     110 INFO     CREATE INDEX index_drives_model_fk ON drives (model)
log.py                     110 INFO     COMMIT
log.py                     110 INFO     CREATE INDEX drives_role_idx ON drives (role)
log.py                     110 INFO     COMMIT
log.py                     110 INFO     CREATE INDEX index_drives_model_fk ON drives (model) <<<<<<---- Why create index_drives_model_fk twice?
log.py                     110 INFO     ROLLBACK
```

If you notice the last 6 lines of the snippet above, you will see that `index_drives_model_fk` is being created twice and hence the error. My question: what makes sqlalchemy emit two index creations to the `drives` table, but the `models` table (and the associated indices) seems to be created correctly? I can also confirm if I remove the `drives_role_idx` and `index_drives_model_fk` from the postgres `drive` table, then things work correctly as expected.

Comment: have you been able to figure it out?

Comment: @pkaleta Sorry, I didn't.

Comment: See https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7366